# How do I make the Axes objects have the same size as the one in the default figure size?

Tags: matplotlib

This code gives one figure with one [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#id2) object

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.get_size_inches()
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.plot([0,0,1,1,0], [0,1,1,0,0], linewidth=10)
```

The default figure size is `array([6., 4.])`

[image]

This code gives one figure with 2 [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#id2) objects

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8)) 
for i in range(2):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
    plt.xlim([0, 1])
    plt.ylim([0, 1])
    plt.plot([0,0,1,1,0], [0,1,1,0,0], color='red', linewidth=10)
```

I've set the figsize as twice as the first figure.

[image]

However, the [Axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/axes_api.html#id2) object (in blue) in the first figure is bigger than any one (in red) in the 2nd.

How do I make the Axes objects have the same size as the one in the first figure?

Comment: If you try to set the subplot to no size specification, it will be reduced to the default width. However, the height is also reduced. This is reduced by the aspect ratio of the default image size. This is my guess.

Comment: To validate the size, this will make it clear.`fig = plt.figure(facecolor='#ffffe0')`

Comment: Constrained_layout will get you very close.  If you want then precisely the same size you’ll have to do a bit of math.  There is also the proplot package thts does layout by axes size rather than figure size.